# When creating new basic task Windows scheduler getting stuck

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, windows-sbs-2011, task-scheduler

I have Windows SBS 2011 server with one secondary Windows 2003 domain controller, no other problems found, but when I try to create new basic task on the SBS, all works well till pressing the Finish button. After pressing Finish the dialog window stuck and I can't finish adding the task.

I tried to restart Schedule service via **SYSTEM** account (service begins to stop and waits forever in stop pending state), I checked permissions also of ***c:\windows\tasks***, nothing unusual found, I have to restart the server.